# Gitlab.com CI cannot logon to SSH server

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Most of the repositories of my private projects are hosted on a private repository on gitlab.com (the hosted solution, not a privately hosted gitlab server). The sites are hosted on a digitalocean VPS.

I want to use gitlab CI to have every commit on the `develop` branch automatically deployed on the test server. Since I already have a clone of the repository on this test server the easiest way to automatically deploy seems to have gitlab-ci connect to the ssh server, and trigger a git pull.

The `gitlab-ci.yml` I have now (ssh before_script copied from http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/ssh_keys/README.html).

```
deploy to test:
  environment: test
  only:
  - develop
  before_script:
    # Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
    # (change apt-get to yum if you use a CentOS-based image)
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    # Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

    # add ssh key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")

    # disable host key checking (NOTE: makes you susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks)
    # WARNING: use only in docker container, if you use it with shell you will overwrite your user's ssh config
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config

  script:
     # Try and connect to the test server
    - ssh [myname]@[mydomain.com] "cd /var/www/test.[projectname].com/ && git pull"
```

The result of a commit on `develop` in the gitlab pipelines:

```
$ ssh [myname]@[mydomain.com] "cd /var/www/test.[projectname].com/ && git pull"
Warning: Permanently added '[mydomain.com],[255.255.255.255]' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

Permission denied, please try again.

Permission denied, please try again.

Permission denied (publickey,password).

ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

I have the private key of my local user on my laptop added to the `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` variable on gitlab. The private key should work since I can connect to the server from my laptop without providing a password.

Does anyone have this working, how can the gitlab.com worker connect to the ssh server?

Comment: Hi @vityrus, did you manage  to connect using ssh and perform command on the distant host ?

Comment: I understand this is a 2 year old question, but for reference to an accepted answer to a similar question on ssh in GitLab CI - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54219136/4864827)

Comment: I am having similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57290734/ssh-host-key-verification-failed-inside-gitlab-ci

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't do this:

```
# add ssh key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
- ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
```

The `ssh-agent` is not getting the key context, nor the FD. You should store the key in some temporary file and then add it to the agent (and potentially remove the file, if it is not needed anymore):

```
# add ssh key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
- echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > key
- chmod 600 key
- ssh-add key
- rm key
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion Jakuje! 
First time I tried your actual code:
`
    @         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
    Permissions 0644 for 'key' are too open.
    It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
    This private key will be ignored.
`

Comment: Then you probably need to make sure it has proper permissions (`chmod 600 key` after the writing).

Comment: I also did that (sorry, having trouble with the comments, posting code does not have multi line code). 

It gave exactly the same output as my original attempt: `Permission denied, please try again.` x 2

Comment: Then the key is probably wrong. How does it look like? Can you get verbose logs using `-vvv` switches to `ssh`? What is the output of other commands than `ssh`?

Comment: `$ chmod 600 key
$ cat key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAsGA79Fa....`

Some way I can share the entire output (incl -vvv) with you? Pastebin?
I saw one strange thing there... it is looking for: ` /root/.ssh/config`
 while I never refer to 'root'.

Comment: Edit the question, or use the pastebin. The script is probably running under the root and `/root/` is its home directory. It is default behavior to search for config there.

Comment: Since it is looking for /root/.ssh/id_rsa I tried putting the key there: `echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa` 
Output does not change: 
 http://pastebin.com/aJQLj9PN